# Fedora 28 boot kernels menu - how to skip?

Tags: fedora, boot, linux-kernel

When I start Fedora it tries to give me the options to boot from other boot kernels, how do I stop this?

[image: ss1]

Comment: you could try the GRUB `lock` command,

Answer (score 4):

Those are not other partitions. Those are alternate boot kernels — older versions, as well as a failsafe (the `0-rescue`) one. You can get rid of them by removing the corresponding kernel — but generally there's no need to. By default, the update system will only keep the most recent three (including the one you were running when updates were last applied). If it happens that a security or bugfix update has a regression on your hardware, you can boot to the older kernel.

Comment: can i stop it from doing this?  it really takes a long time to boot?

Comment: removing options won't make booting appreciably faster, you can reduce the timeout,  or just reboot less often.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to install [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) and disable the menu.

By installing [Grub Customizer (Fedora pkgs)](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/grub-customizer) I was able to disable the menu completely, and potentially reduce the time.

[image]